# Lodash not running each function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to:

1. Filter a collection of objects.
2. Run a function over each item of the filtered collection.

I'm using lodash, if i write this statement

```
_.each(_.filter(sut.Nodes, nodeFilter), test);
```

The test function get executed filtered collection length times

But if i write the statement like this

```
_(sut.Nodes)
  .filter(nodeFilter)
  .map(test);
```

The test function is not executed any time.

Could anyone explain why?.

I supose is something lazy related. If it is, how can I fire the execution?

Answer (score 4):

Chained expressions are "lazy", in that they aren't executed until you request the results. You can do that, for instance, by using [`.value()`](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-value) at the end of your chain:

```
_(sut.Nodes)
  .filter(nodeFilter)
  .map(test)
  .value();
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. i've tested and it works. Nice to know chained expressions are lazy

Comment: @borjagómez if you find the answer correct or useful, please upvote it or mark it as correct. thanks :)